# Search within Datagrid and scroll & select newly added item

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using the Telerik Datagrid control to display 100's of records. In my app the user selects a they want to edit and I use a form to allow the user to update the record. 
Likewise, if they wish to add a new record they click 'Add' and a blank version of the form appears.

I'm not binding direct to a data source. I'm providing the data to the grid by setting the Itemsource to my List of records.

When the user has edited a record I can scroll and select the edited record quite easily:

```
            //find row index of selected item
            var lastRowUpdated = RadGridAssetTable.Items.IndexOf(this.RadGridAssetTable.SelectedItem);

            // move to index following edit
            RadGridAssetTable.ScrollIndexIntoView(lastRowUpdated);
            RadGridAssetTable.SelectedItem = lastRowUpdated;
```

However, when I add a new record I cannot figure out how to programmatically scroll and select the newly added grid item.

Effectively I want to search the grid rows for the (hidden) record ID, select the row index in the control and scroll to it

There doesn't appear to be a way of searching data in the grid programmatically, can someone point in the correct direction on how to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved like this.

```
 var lastRowUpdated = 0;
        var i = 0;

        if (_assetsavedData.AssetId == -1)
        {
            foreach (var rowItem in from object row in RadGridAssetTable.Items select row as AssetLinked)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(rowItem.AssetItems.AssetCommonName);

                if (rowItem.AssetItems.AssetCommonName.Equals(_assetsavedData.AssetCommonName))
                {
                    lastRowUpdated = i;
                    Debug.WriteLine("found at " + i);
                    break;
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastRowUpdated = RadGridAssetTable.Items.IndexOf(this.RadGridAssetTable.SelectedItem);
        }
```